# check href indexOf for two values using || (or)

Tags: href, indexof

I've had a look around and seen how to use || (or) in an if statement but I'm stuck.  This piece of code is currently working, it finds mydomain.com/elearning:

```
if (obj.href.indexOf('mydomain.com/elearning') == -1){
```

in addition to searching for 'mydomain.com/elearning' I also need to check for 'mailto' so I tried:

```
if (obj.href.indexOf('mydomain.com/elearning' || 'mailto') == -1){
```

but it only matches the first one, not mailto.  If I swap them around it will find mailto but not mydomain.com/elearning

Any help is greatly appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: `if (obj.href.indexOf('mydomain.com/elearning' ) == -1 || obj.href.indexOf('mailto' ) ==-1 ){`

Comment: thanks for your reply gkiko, really appreciate it.  I'd tried your suggestions and it was finding nothing so I tried swapping || or && and now it works.